# CSS and noscript visibility puzzle

Tags: css, noscript

I work on a 100% Javascript site that uses a CSS class on the `body` to explicitly hide everything (`display:none`), then enables blocks as needed (unusual yes, but I can't change the architecture).

I'd like to display a `noscript` message to users without js enabled, but we run into a CSS puzzle. `noscript` must exist within the `body`. Unlike other blocks on the page, the `noscript` element can't be forced to become visible, as far as I can tell. The weird thing is that when I select the `noscript` element with Webkit Inspector, it "claims" that the noscript element is visible. But no matter what, nothing appears on screen with js disabled.

I've done two test cases - one with standard noscript, and another with a hidden div. Either way, the hidden element remains hidden no matter what. My theory is that it's simply not possible to selectively display an element that's nested inside a hidden parent element (i.e. `noscript` within `body`).

Here's my simple test case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body{
            display:none;
        }

        body noscript  {
          display:block;
          visibility:visible;
          color:black;
        }  
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Normal text</p>

    <noscript>
        <p>This is is noscript</p>
    </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

[Later: Example simplified for clarity]

Is this solvable? Thanks.

Comment: "it's simply not possible to selectively display an element that's nested inside a hidden parent element" -- that statement sounds correct to me.

Comment: Do you honestly need `display:none` on the body? Can't you encourage whoever makes these decisions to let you have two divs, one visible by default to show the error message, the other hidden, and your js hides the first and shows the second the first thing it does? (Your js would have to show the body... so it may as well show a div instead).

Comment: Chris - Probably not, unfortunately. This is a design decision at a pretty high level. I can lobby...

Comment: Chris - I think you're right - this is the only way I can come up with to make it work. Now it's just a matter of lobbying for this change.

Comment: Chris if you want to post this as an actual answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than making the body hidden:

```
body { display: none; }
```

Can you make everything **in** the body hidden?

```
body * { display: none; }
```

Then override that for the noscript - or a div within the noscript, e.g.

```
body noscript #requirements { display: block; }
```

---

**Edit**

Revisiting this after shacker's comment and looking at my test page with Firebug, it became obvious what the problem was.

`body * { display: none; }` applies to *everything* within the body *at any depth*, so even if I correctly make the `<noscript>` display correctly, the contents *inside* it still don't display.

The solution is to target more specifically, using a *child* selector instead of a *descendant* selector.

Given this html, I see nothing when javascript is enabled, but I see the contents of the `<noscript>` block, which lists my site requirements, when javascript is disabled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body > * {
                display: none;
            }
            body > noscript {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>A normal text block, within a &lt;p&gt;</p>

        <div>A standard &lt;div&gt; with only this text in it</div>

        <noscript>
            <div id="requirements">
                <p>
                This is my noscript div, that is, a &lt;div&gt;
                within the &lt;noscript&gt; tag.
                </p>
                <p>
                This site requires that javascript and cookies are enabled.
                </p>
            </div>
        </noscript>

    </body>
</html>
```

The rule for `body > *` hides all immediate children of the body, and therefore *their* descendants too, while the `body > noscript` rule reveals the content of the noscript block, and of course that block only displays if javascript is disabled.

Comment: Stephen, thanks, but that unfortunately does not work (try applying it to the example above).

Comment: @shacker - you were absolutely correct - see my updated answer.

Comment: Stephen, this is absolutely brilliant. I was just about to propose a more involved solution to the team, but you've nailed it with child selectors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, since you've hidden the parent element, no matter what styling you add to its children you won't be able to see it until you unhide the body. Your best bet would be to change it so you're not hiding the body by default but instead inside your first script tag in the example add a simple

```
document.body.className='specialbody';
```

This will add the `specialbody` class before anything is rendered, but only if javascript is working.